# How should I report earnings from Apple (from selling mobile applications in the App Store) in 1040 form in USA?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, form-1099, form-1040x, schedule-c

How should I report earnings from Apple (from selling mobile applications in the App Store) in 1040 form in USA? I'm permanent resident of USA.

1. Can I fill Form 1040 with Schedule C as individual without registration of any business like sole proprietor, LLC, etc.?
2. Will I be able to write off 30% of Apple's commission as expenses when report 1040 form as individual?
3. Will I be able to write off expenses like home office and medical insurance when report 1040 form as individual?
4. How should I calculate income and commission for sales worldwide? Apple write all values in original currency. It's hard work to calculate them in US dollars.
5. What rate of exchange should be used? Apple write not accurate rates for some currencies. So I suggest we should not use them.

Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: My tax adviser wrote: "In order to write-off business expenses, you need to have your business registered, for state and federal tax purposes. If you don’t, IRS can re-classify your business expenses as hobby… and hobby losses are not deductible."

Comment: I can't answer the specific tax questions, and even though I understand the desire to do everything yourself (I do my taxes myself), this definitely sounds like an area where hiring a pro, if only to get set up to the point you can handle it yourself, would be money well spent.

Comment: Does Apple give you a Form 1099-MISC for this?

Comment: Hobby losses are not deductible, but hobby expenses might be in limited circumstances.

Comment: @Altaveron What does your tax advisor mean by "have your business registered for state and federal tax purposes"? If you're a sole proprietor with no employees, I don't believe that IRS has a mechanism for you to "register" even voluntarily. State laws may vary, but in my state you also don't need to register in this case unless you need to collect some special tax like sales tax.

Comment: Apple report 1099-K form to IRS for part of earnings. The tax advisor says WA state requires any business activity to be registered. But in WA, I do not even have to pay taxes. Is it really truth?

Comment: @Altaveron you do have to pay taxes in WA. It is called B&O tax, and it is based on your gross receipts.

Comment: My tax adviser even don't said me about B&O tax... Will it be taxed as royalties with .00484 rate? When and where should I report B&O tax? And can SSN be used for it? Or it's required to register EIN for every sole proprietor in WA?

Comment: It seems earnings from App Store can't be reported using SSN number in WA state and business must be registered: http://dor.wa.gov/content/DoingBusiness/RegisterMyBusiness/Default.aspx

Comment: Should developers also pay retail sales tax in WA state???

Comment: How to determine what retail sales tax rate should be used? Apple doesn't provide coordinates of every sale. How developers have to pay this tax?

Comment: @Altaveron Apple is in California, which doesn't charge sales tax on software licenses. You only transact with Apple, so you don't care where the end users are.

Comment: Apple just transfer money from users over the world. Apple does NOT pay developers. Users pay, Apple only transfer money.

Comment: @littleadv If I should not pay Retail sales tax why I should pay B&O tax?

Comment: @Altaveron because that's how the State of Washington laws work? Not sure I follow your logic. In any case, you mentioned you have a tax adviser - shouldn't you be talking to that person?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I fill Form 1040 with Schedule C as individual without registration of any business like sole proprietor, LLC, etc.?

Yes. The IRS doesn't care. "Sole Proprietor" is registered when born, usually in a hospital. If you have a birth certificate - you're registered.

> Will I be able to write off 30% of Apple's commission as expenses when report 1040 form as individual?

Of course.

> Will I be able to write off expenses like home office and medical insurance when report 1040 form as individual?

That may be a bit trickier as there are specific rules as to how and when you can deduct those. Generally, if you have a net-positive income from your Schedule C operation after deducting those and all the rest of the requirements are satisfied,  you can deduct those.

> How should I calculate income and commission for sales worldwide?
>   Apple write all values in original currency. It's hard work to
>   calculate them in US dollars.

I suggest using a calculator. That will make it easier somewhat.

> What rate of exchange should be used? Apple write not accurate rates
>   for some currencies. So I suggest we should not use them.

You should use the [Department of Treasury](https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/fsreports/rpt/treasRptRateExch/treasRptRateExch_home.htm) rates, and you should use the rate of the day of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You wrote 'You should use the Department of Treasury rates, and you should use the rate of the day of the transaction.' But it's absolutely impossible to track every of tens of thousands transactions to calculate them using different rates. I should calculate it 8 hours per day if it's really required. I'm sure there is more simpler way to report earnings from App Store. Can you help to find it?

Comment: @Altaveron are you being paid for each transaction separately????

Comment: Only 1 transaction per month without Apple's commission. But Apple report 1099-K for values including commission. So developers must report gross income in Schedule C and Apple's commission. By the way, Apple doesn't provide exact dates for every app sale. So it's impossible to calculate each app sale by separate rate.

Comment: @Altaveron so **you** have a single transaction a month, what do you care what Apple has?

Comment: 1 money transaction but many app sales. As I know I must report all app sales and Apple's commission in Schedule C. App sales are taxable - not cumulative money transactions from Apple.

Comment: @Altaveron if you don't trust your tax adviser - get another one. Don't expect coming here trying to get free tax prep work. If you don't know how to fill the forms - there are software to help you, or pay someone to fill them for you.

Comment: I can't rate any tax adviser if I don't know truth myself. So, I'm trying to understand my common tax obligations in WA state when I receive income from Apple. And I don't understand should I pay or not: 1) B&O tax; 2) retail sales tax; 3) what rates should be used to calculate international sales. I'll be appreciate for your help!

Comment: Also I'm not sure if I should report gross income from end-users or I can report only values based on transactions from Apple. In the second way 1099-K form may report greater income than I file in my Schedule C. And then IRS reject 1040 form.

Comment: @Altaveron I'm sorry if I made an appearance of a free tax adviser. I'm not. I know about the B&O tax in your State, but I'm not familiar enough with it to provide you any guidance. If you don't trust your tax adviser - get another one, otherwise follow the advice you paid for.